# restart so that nextval is the next unused id

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence

I've got a script which copies table data from one DB to another, however the ID column is backed by a sequence so when a new record is inserted into the destination table the `nextval(seq)` is returning the wrong value.

I need to update the sequence so that it starts at the next available ID.

I want to do something like:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE seq_id RESTART WITH
    (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl);
```

The above produces a syntax error however.

Can anyone suggest an alternative approach?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
DO $$
  SELECT INTO m MAX(id) FROM tbl;
  EXECUTE 'ALTER SEQUENCE seq_id RESTART WITH ' || m;
END$$;
```

or, better yet, see this question:

- [How to reset postgres' primary key sequence when it falls out of sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync)

Comment: thanks for the answer, i'm running this as an echo piped into psql .. can you tell me how to escape the whole command into one ?

Comment: you can use the `setval` function rather than having to dynamically build a `alter sequence` statement; simpler, but doesn't make any real difference if you're doing these one-by-one.