# Postgres manually alter sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl, database-sequence

I'm trying to set a sequence to a specific value.

```
SELECT setval('payments_id_seq'), 21, true;
```

This gives an error:

> `ERROR:  function setval(unknown) does not exist`

Using `ALTER SEQUENCE` doesn't seem to work either?

```
ALTER SEQUENCE payments_id_seq LASTVALUE 22;
```

How can this be done?

Ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html

Comment: It would appear that `setval()` has at least two arguments.

Answer (score 554, accepted):

The parentheses are misplaced:

```
SELECT setval('payments_id_seq', 21, true);  -- next value will be 22
```

Otherwise you're calling `setval` with a single argument, while it requires two or three.

This is the same as `SELECT setval('payments_id_seq', 21)`

Comment: What does the last argument "true" means?

Comment: `true` means that the next value will be the number provided + 1, in this case 22. `false` means that the next value would be the number provided, or 21. By default, setval will behave as if `true` was chosen. More details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-sequence.html

Comment: an advantage of the `select setval` syntax over `alter sequence` is that you can use nested queries in it, for example to `select max(id) from payments`.

Comment: @mariotomo that's an excellent point, and one of the easiest ways to ensure you don't accidently introduce a latent bug by setting the sequence number lower than the current max

Comment: Another advantage of using such functions is running queries like `select setval('new_id_seq', nextval('old_id_seq'), false);` which helps to migrate

Comment: In case when you need to continue sequence from the value of max id, you should use `SELECT setval('payment_id_seq', (select coalesce(max(id), 0) from payment), true);`

Answer (score 291):

This syntax isn't valid in *any* version of PostgreSQL:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE payments_id_seq LASTVALUE 22
```

This would work:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE payments_id_seq RESTART WITH 22;
```

And is equivalent to:

```
SELECT setval('payments_id_seq', 22, FALSE);
```

More in the *current* manual for [`ALTER SEQUENCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersequence.html) and [sequence functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html).

Note that `setval()` expects either `(regclass, bigint)` or `(regclass, bigint, boolean)`. In the above example I am providing *untyped literals*. That works too. But if you feed typed variables to the function you may need explicit **type casts** to satisfy function type resolution. Like:

```
SELECT setval(my_text_variable::regclass, my_other_variable::bigint, FALSE);
```

To restart the sequence of a `serial` or `IDENTITY` column after the currently greatest column value (without even knowing the sequence name):

```
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('payments', 'id')
            , COALESCE(max(id) + 1, 1)
            , false)
FROM   payments;
```

See:

- [How to reset Postgres' primary key sequence when it falls out of sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync/23390399#23390399)
- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-table-column/9875517#9875517)

---

For repeated operations you might be interested in:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE payments_id_seq START WITH 22; -- set default
ALTER SEQUENCE payments_id_seq RESTART;       -- without value
```

`START [WITH]` stores a default `RESTART` number, which is used for subsequent `RESTART` calls without value. You need Postgres 8.4 or later for the last part.

Comment: `ALTER SEQUENCE [sequence] RESTART WITH (SELECT MAX(col) from table);` does not work, whereas `SELECT setval('sequence', (SELECT (MAX(col) from table), TRUE);` does work. I get a syntax error. (Postgres 9.4)

Comment: No subquery allowed in a DDL command ("utility command"). See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36025963/939860

Comment: @NuclearPeon that doesn't work either. Always gives syntax error function setval(unknown, numeric, boolean) does not exist.

Comment: @MitalPritmani: You may need type casts. Consider added instructions above.

Comment: @NuclearPeon I think you mean `SELECT setval('sequence', (SELECT MAX(col) from table), TRUE);` otherwise your parens don't line up.

Comment: @dland: Aside: shorter & faster equivalent: `SELECT setval('seq', max(col)) FROM tbl;` See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23390399/939860

Comment: I like the last one as it allows me to calculate the value :)

Comment: FWIW, 'ALTER SEQUENCE RESTART WITH' and setval are not 100% equivalent - in my testing, ALTER is blocking, and setval is not, which makes setval suitable for concurrent updates from different transactions - a feature I needed.

Answer (score 74):

Use `select setval('payments_id_seq', 21, true);`

`setval` contains 3 parameters:

- 1st parameter is `sequence_name`
- 2nd parameter is Next `nextval`
- 3rd parameter is optional.

The use of true or false in 3rd parameter of setval is as follows:

```
SELECT setval('payments_id_seq', 21);           // Next nextval will return 22
SELECT setval('payments_id_seq', 21, true);     // Same as above 
SELECT setval('payments_id_seq', 21, false);    // Next nextval will return 21
```

The better way to avoid hard-coding of sequence name, next sequence value and to handle empty column table correctly, you can use the below way:

```
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('table_name', 'id'), coalesce(max(id), 0)+1 , false) FROM table_name;
```

where `table_name` is the name of the table, `id` is the `primary key` of the table

Comment: Thank you! Last expression is exactly what I was looking for. It allows me to reserve the sequence values in order to insert by batch afterwards.

Comment: This is the most correct answer, the last SQL snippet is the most generic and effective.

Comment: First comment 'Next nextval will return 22'.   Just if the increment value of the sequence is 1. It will be 21 + increment value. Third comment 'Next nextval will return 21'. That's always true. Sometimes for generating less network traffic the app gets e.g. 10 ids to use without the need to ask 10 times. And next time the nextval return value will be increased by 10 instead of 1.
See increment here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html

Answer (score 10):

select setval('sequence_name', sequence_value)

Answer (score 7):

I don't try changing sequence via `setval`. But using `ALTER` I was issued how to write sequence name properly. And this only work for me:

1. Check required sequence name using `SELECT * FROM information_schema.sequences;`
2. `ALTER SEQUENCE public."table_name_Id_seq" restart {number};`

   In my case it was `ALTER SEQUENCE public."Services_Id_seq" restart 8;`

Also there is a page on [wiki.postgresql.org](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Fixing_Sequences) where describes a way to generate sql script to fix sequences in all database tables at once. Below the text from link:

> Save this to a file, say 'reset.sql'
>
> ```
> SELECT 'SELECT SETVAL(' ||
>        quote_literal(quote_ident(PGT.schemaname) || '.' || quote_ident(S.relname)) ||
>        ', COALESCE(MAX(' ||quote_ident(C.attname)|| '), 1) ) FROM ' ||
>        quote_ident(PGT.schemaname)|| '.'||quote_ident(T.relname)|| ';'
> FROM pg_class AS S,
>      pg_depend AS D,
>      pg_class AS T,
>      pg_attribute AS C,
>      pg_tables AS PGT
> WHERE S.relkind = 'S'
>     AND S.oid = D.objid
>     AND D.refobjid = T.oid
>     AND D.refobjid = C.attrelid
>     AND D.refobjsubid = C.attnum
>     AND T.relname = PGT.tablename
> ORDER BY S.relname;
> ```
>
> Run the file and save its output in a way that doesn't include the
> usual headers, then run that output. Example:
>
> ```
> psql -Atq -f reset.sql -o temp
> psql -f temp
> rm temp
> ```

And the output will be a set of sql commands which look exactly like this:

```
SELECT SETVAL('public."SocialMentionEvents_Id_seq"', COALESCE(MAX("Id"), 1) ) FROM public."SocialMentionEvents";
SELECT SETVAL('public."Users_Id_seq"', COALESCE(MAX("Id"), 1) ) FROM public."Users";
```

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me:

```
SELECT pg_catalog.setval('public.hibernate_sequence', 3, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

This alter it works for me :

```
ALTER SEQUENCE payments_id_seq
    RESTART 17;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For most of the people `setval` command should work, mine was not working so I used `pg_catalog.setval`.

This one worked for me:

```
select pg_catalog.setval('<sequence_variable_name>', <sequence_number_you_want>, true);
```

The setval function alone didn't work for me.

```
SELECT pg_catalog.setval('payments_id_seq', 21, true); -- next will be 22
```

[See the docs for more info](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html)