# After updating table id via csv file when trying to add new field getting - duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: django, postgresql, csv

Problem.
After successful data migration from csv files to django /Postgres application .

When I try to add a new record via the application interface   getting - duplicate key value violates unique constraint.(Since i had id's in my csv files -i use them as keys )

Basically the app try to generate id's that  already  migrated.
After each attempt ID increments by one so if I have 160 record I have to get this error 160 times and then when I try 160 times  the time 161   record  saves ok.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Sounds like your sequence needs an update. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8750984

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't have an actual `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, at least not in the way that MySQL does. Instead it has a special `SERIAL`. This creates a four-byte `INT` column and attaches a trigger to it. Behind the scenes, if PostgreSQL sees that there is no value in that ID column, it checks the value of a sequence created when that column was created.

You can see this by:

```
SELECT 
    TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_DEFAULT 
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME='<your-table>' AND COLUMN_NAME = '<your-id-column>';
```

You should see something like:

```
 table_name   | column_name               | column_default
--------------+---------------------------+-------------------------------------
 <your-table> | <your-id-column>          | nextval('<table-name>_<your-id-column>_seq'::regclass)
(1 row)
```

To resolve your particular issue, you're going to need to reset the value of the sequence (named `<table-name>_<your-id-column>_seq`) to reflect the current index.

```
ALTER SEQUENCE your_name_your_id_column_seq RESTART WITH 161;
```

Credit where credit is due.

- [Sequence syntax is here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745051/postgres-manually-alter-sequence/8750984#8750984)
- [Finding the name is here.](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4B194EBD.4050803@fmed.uba.ar)