# Reset sequence in jpa

Tags: postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot 2 with spring data jpa, hibernate and posgres.
I need to reset a sequence every 1 day of the year, because we use current + ''+ sequence id.

Is there a way to reset a sequence with jpa?

Answer (score 2):

A pure JPA way to reset a sequence does not exist, and resetting sequences is not even supported by all databases. That being said, you could try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745051/postgres-manually-alter-sequence) with a native query (`em.createNativeQuery(...).executeUpdate()`) or the [stored procedure API](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-call-postgresql-functions-from-hibernate/) if you absolutely must use JPA for the job.