# Primary key with two field

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I search a way to create a primary key with two values.

I need to get the current year add it to a sequence (this sequence need to be restarted at the beginning of every year.

**For 2018**

```
First record: 20181
Second record: 20182
```

**For 2019**

```
First record: 20191
```

I was thinking to use `embededid` who include a sequence that I would reset every year.

Edit

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Cars {

    @EmbeddedId
    private EmbedddedCarsKey id;

}

@Embeddable
public class EmbedddedCarsKey implements Serializable {

    private int year;

    @SequenceGenerator(name = "cars_id_seq", sequenceName = "cars_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "cars_id_seq")
    private Integer seq

    public EmbedddedCarsKey();
      year = LocalDate.now().getYear();
    }

}
```

When I try to save I get

```
Cars cars = new Cars();
cars.setName("Honda");

carsRepository.save(cars);
```

> org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated
>   for:class com.ush.mcl.model.Cars

Edit 2

tried that...

```
cars = new Cars
EmbedddedCarsKey key= new EmbedddedCarsKey();
cars.setId(key);
```

but seq value stay null;

Comment: Perhaps there is a better alternative, but we'd need some clarification on the reasons behind the need of a PK that consists of the YEAR and an sequence which resets annually.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49986489

Comment: @Naros, probably a client request...