# Resetting sequence in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

#### Setup:

I did create a table in PostgreSQL, with a column **id** serial Primary Key.
Looking at the properties of the column in pgAdmin I can see:

**Datatype:** Integer

**Default:** nextval('items_id_seq'::regclass)

*(So if I'm not mistaking i did create it using the 'serial' key-word.)*

Now in my backend-code I'm using the method: jpaRepository.deleteAllInBatch(), which 'truncates' my whole table.

#### *Problem*

When after this call I do add records to the table again, i can see that the id of the following record continues from the id of the last record I had in the table.

#### *Question:*

Is there a way to reinitialize the id-serial when doing the jpaRepository.deleteAllInBatch() so that records begin with id = 0 again?

Comment: You can reset a sequence, but why bother? You're not supposed to care about the actual values, just that they're a primary key.

Comment: Have a look at this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49986489/reset-sequence-in-jpa?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I'm bothering 'cause firstly I don't use this primary key as foreign key, so resetting the sequence shouldn't create problems. And I have quite a few times where I delete 1000+ records and add 1000+ records again. I'm afraid that not this year, but maybe next year I would be reaching the sequence-integer-limit

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

```
ALTER SEQUENCE seq RESTART WITH 1;
UPDATE t SET idcolumn=nextval('seq');
```

For more detail

[How to reset sequence in postgres and fill id column with new data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678110/how-to-reset-sequence-in-postgres-and-fill-id-column-with-new-data)

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll just do it manually myself every year or so. Thanks