# Using hibernate sequence as general sequence in application

Tags: hibernate, jhipster

I can see that all applications created by ***[jhipster]***, are using **hibernate_sequence** as the general sequence for all entities. Normally I create a sequence for each entity. So, in my ***[jhipster]*** application I have to modify the entity file to customize the sequence name instead of **hibernate_sequence**. Why you are using general **hibernate_sequence**? Is it best practice instead of using new sequence for each entity? or you have a target behind this?

In my case, I have a huge number of entities with a huge number of concurrent access. Is it ok to use one sequence for all those entities? Or should I create a sequence for each one?

Answer (score 0):

As answered in the github website to this same question, there is a *long* talk about this. I also think it's best to have single sequences for each entity, but this will not be implemented (for now)

Comment: I've inserted rows directly in my database, now when I try to insert data from the application throws 'org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint', is there any way to update the sequence of the entity since only one sequence is used?

Comment: you can check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745051/ddg#8750984