# How to insert rows with the serial column catching up from the largest value in the table in Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, nextval, currval

I have a table like the following:

```
create table my_table
(
    "ID"            serial not null,
    "Name"          varchar(500)
);
```

Without changing the property of the table, is there any clean way to insert a new row to this table (already has values, so "ID" does not start from 1) such that the column "ID" keeps incrementing?
Currently, if I insert a new row `Charlie` (without specifying the ID column) to the table:

```
ID    |    Name
----------------
1     |    Alice
2     |    Bob
```

It will become

```
ID    |    Name
----------------
1     |    Alice
2     |    Bob
1     |    Charlie
```

Then as I keep inserting, the serial counter keeps incrementing. Is there any way I can start from 3? I've tried `currval()`, `nextval()` and `lastval()`, but they all seem to start from 1 even though I have a serial column with values already.
If I have to end up changing the properties of this table, any way I can change it such that I won't have to worry about the serial column when I insert new rows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgres manually alter sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745051/postgres-manually-alter-sequence)

Comment: @MikeOrganek Thanks for the suggestion but not quite hmm so what if I don't know the last value? Obviously, I can do a select first and count, but just wondering if there is any clean/proper way to do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks a lot! I think I am going with this solution!