# Rails PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "table_pkey"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I created something like a JSON backup for my project's database, and then I populate it like this

```
Model.find_or_initialize_by(:id => h["id"]).update(h)}
```

being h a hash of the model attributes for an instance.

The records are effectively created, but when I want to create a new record, rails rises this error

```
PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "table_pkey"
```

What could I be doing wrong? It happens for all models which were created using scaffold, here a migration as an example.

```
class CreateModel < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :models do |t|
      t.string :attribute1
      t.string :attribute2
      t.string :attribute3

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using sequential integer id's for your table according to the migration. This works well enough if you allow the database to assign id's for you. Every time a new record comes in, database takes the next number on the list and assigns it to that record (simplifying here).

Lets assume the database id sequence is currently at `3` and the records you imported have ids `4`, `37` and `143025`. Inserting a new record to the database, database says id is `3`, all good, sequence is now at `4`. Inserting another one, database says id is `4`. Trying to insert it, but there already is a `4` in the database.

```
PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "table_pkey"
```

A few possible solutions:

1. After importing, change the database id sequence to something bigger than the largest id you imported. (hacky, but works) [Postgres manually alter sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745051/postgres-manually-alter-sequence)
2. Import the items without hardcoding their id-s. (complicated)
3. Change your database to use uuid-s instead of integer id-s (architectural change, difficult if the app is live, best solution if you're still in development)
4. Use a proper database backup system rather than building your own. [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgdump.html)