# How to reset the auto generated primary key in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, auto-increment, ddl, database-sequence

My class for the table `topics` is as below. The primary key is autogenerated serial key. While testing, I deleted rows from the table and was trying to re-insert them again. The UUID is not getting reset.

```
class Topics(db.Model):
    """ User Model for different topics """
    __tablename__ = 'topics'

    uuid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    topics_name = db.Column(db.String(256),index=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Post %r>' % self.topics_name
```

I tried the below command to reset the key

```
ALTER SEQUENCE topics_uuid_seq RESTART WITH 1;
```

It did not work.
I would appreciate any form of suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's indeed a [**`serial`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) ID, you can reset the owned `SEQUENCE` with:

```
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('topics', 'uuid'), max(uuid)) FROM topics;
```

See:

[How to reset postgres' primary key sequence when it falls out of sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync/23390399#23390399)

But why would the name be `uuid`? [UUID](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html) are not `integer` numbers and not `serial`. Also, it's not entirely clear what's going wrong, when you write:

> The UUID is not getting reset.

About `ALTER SEQUENCE ... RESTART`:

- [Postgres manually alter sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745051/postgres-manually-alter-sequence/8750984#8750984)

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid duplicate id errors that may arise when resetting the sequence try:

```
UPDATE table SET id = DEFAULT;
ALTER SEQUENCE seq RESTART;
UPDATE table SET id = DEFAULT;
```

For added context:

1. 'table' = your table name
2. 'id' = your id column name
3. 'seq' = find the name of your sequence with:

   ```
   SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence('table', 'id');
   ```