# How to change table primary key with existing data from character to serial

Tags: postgresql, primary-key

I am working with a colleague who is new to Postgres and databases in general. She created a table with a column ID of character varying type and made that the primary key. So apparently, when running a python script to populate the table, she incremented the IDs herself and inserted them as strings. She inserted a rather large amount of data into the table, so I would like to fix it rather than having her start over. I need to change the ID column to type serial (which she should have made it to begin with) but I don't think I can just change the type since it contains character data. Can anyone tell me the best way to approach this?

Comment: What does the existing character data look like?  "1", "2", etc?  One way or another, you should be able to create a new column, populate it from the current key, and then drop the existing primary and add the new one.

Comment: Are there any foreign keys referring to the ID?

Comment: no, no foreign keys

Answer (score 2):

[`serial`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) is not a real type. It's an integer column with an associated sequence. When altering an existing column you have to do this work yourself.

I'll assume the values are integers, they're just stored as text.

```
-- Alter the ID column to integer, and cast the values to integers
alter table test alter id type integer using id::integer;

-- Make the ID a generated identity. This is similar to serial.
-- It also creates a sequence.
alter table test alter id add generated by default as identity;

-- Sequences start at 1. This would likely cause a duplicate the next time
-- you inserted a row.
-- Find the sequence attached to the ID column, and change it to start at
-- the next highest ID.
select setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('test', 'id'), coalesce(max(id), 0)+1 , false) from test;
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49493181/14660) for more about that last statement. And see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55300741/14660) for serial vs identity.

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/xJEZzeOl).

---

If the ID values are *not* integers, it's probably best to throw out the ID column and make a new one. This assumes there's no foreign keys referring to that ID, because that gets complicated.

```
-- Drop the old one
alter table test drop id;

-- Add a new primary key.
-- Alternatively, you can `alter table test add id serial primary key`
alter table test add id integer primary key generated by default as identity;
```

The new ID column will be populated in order: 1, 2, 3, ...

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/0uan0mrG).

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/35195105) to review this question.