# How to definitelly fix Potgresql autoincrement problem with unique constraint violation

Tags: auto-increment, unique-constraint, postgresql-14

How to fix Potgresql autoincrement problem with unique constraint violation?
Is there some option in Postgres which set up sequence value after any insert properly?
I am alway getting error when Posgres try to create new row with already inserted id.
I never expirienced something similar on Mysql. Believe there is a way to set up this nonsense definitelly. How is that even possible?

Comment: "Is there some option in Postgres which set up sequence value after any insert properly?" YES. See for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745051/postgres-manually-alter-sequence  and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html "I am alway getting error when Posgres try to create new row with already inserted id" this is the expected behavior when violating unique constraints.

Comment: I am not sure if we understand eachother. I dont want to call SETVAL(...) manually. I want to force Postgresql to do it automatically. I have a script which can set up autoinrements on manual call but it is wrong. Why should I do it? Why Postgres does not handle autoincrements after each inserts by default?