# get_or_create failure with Django and Postgres (duplicate key value violates unique constraint)

Tags: django, postgresql

Thanks for taking time to read my question.

I have a django app with the following model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ...

class Visit(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    ip = models.IPAddressField()
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('profile', 'date', 'ip')
```

In a view:

```
profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk = ...)
get, create = Visit.objects.get_or_create(profile=profile, date=now.date(), ip=request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'])
if create: DO SOMETHING
```

Everything works fine, except that the Postgres Logs are full with duplicate key errors:

```
2012-02-15 14:13:44 CET ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "table_visit_profile_id_key"
2012-02-15 14:13:44 CET STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO "table_visit" ("profile_id", "date", "ip") VALUES (1111, E'2012-02-15', E'xx.xx.xxx.xxx') RETURNING "table_visit"."id"
```

Tried different solution e.g.

```
from django.db import transaction 
from django.db import IntegrityError

@transaction.commit_on_success
def my_get_or_create(prof, ip):    
    try:
        object = Visit.objects.create(profile=prof, date=datetime.now().date(), ip=ip)
    except IntegrityError:
        transaction.commit()
        object = Visit.objects.get(profile=prof, date=datetime.now().date(), ip=ip)
    return object

....

created = my_get_or_create(prof, request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'])
if created: DO SOMETHING
```

This only helps for MySQL? Does anyone know how to avaid the duplicate key value errors for postgres?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/244243/781695

Answer (score 12):

Another possible reason for these errors in `get_or_create()` is data type mismatch in one of the search fields - for example passing `False` instead of `None` into a nullable field. The `.get()` inside `.get_or_create()` will not find it and Django will continue with new row creation - which will fail due to PostgreSQL constraints.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Ended what would have otherwise been a morning-long headache for me.

Comment: I agree with you on this point, when you set query as:

`obj, created = UserPermission.objects.get_or_create(
user=user, boolean_field=boolean_field)`

The boolean field is False, it will always try to create object and raise:
`duplicate key value violates unique constraint`
because you have defined `boolean_field=models.BooleanField(default=False)`

Answer (score 5):

I had issues with get_or_create when using postgres. In the end I abandoned the boilerplate code for traditional:

```
try:
    job_invite  = Invite.objects.get(sender=employer.user, job=job)
except Invite.DoesNotExist:
    job_invite  = Invite(sender=employer.user, job=job)
    job_invite.save()
```

Comment: Although this solution will appear to be working on most sites, it will fail on heavy traffic sites where lots of concurrent requests are at work.

Answer (score 2):

Have you at some point had unique=True set on Visit's profile field?

It looks like there's been a unique constraint generated for postgres that's still in effect. "table_visit_profile_id_key" is what it's auto generated name would be, and naturally it would cause those errors if you're recording multiple visits for a user.

If this is the case, are you using [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) to manage your database changes? If you aren't, grab it!

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL behaves somewhat differently in some subtle queries, which results in `IntegrityError` errors, especially after you switch to **Django 1.6**. Here's the solution - you need to add `select_on_save` option to each failing model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
     ...
     class Meta:
         select_on_save = True
```

It's documented here: [Options.select_on_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.select_on_save)

Comment: What if I am using Django 1.4, and I'm getting integrity errors?