# Is there a shortcut for SELECT * FROM?

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax, psql

There are many useful shortcuts in psql console like `\d` or `\l`.
I wondering is there one for `SELECT * FROM table_name`?
I use this query often for learning purposes so it would be quite helpful not to have to write `select * from ...` all the time.

Comment: You shouldn't write `SELECT *` at all :-)  This is usually considered bad practice (for production queries, of course you can do it for testing): You can't see which columns will be returned and in which order, you usually don't really need all columns and when the table definition is altered this will change the layout of the returned data.

Comment: @dnoeth: There are plenty of cases where you need `SELECT *` and even more where it's just convenient. The fact that it's often (ab)used in places where it shouldn't, does not warrant a general statement like "You shouldn't use it". That like saying: "You shouldn't use knifes".

Comment: @dnoeth I know what you mean but as I said "for learning purposes" ;)

Comment: This is why I prefer GUI clients ;) I just highlight the tablename in the editor, press a shortcut and the tool runs a `select *` for me.

Comment: GUI is a dream. I have only text mode available because course form requires it :)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There is a shortcut for `SELECT * FROM` in **standard SQL**, so you can use it in psql:

```
TABLE tablename;
```

This syntax shorthand can only be used with a limited range of clauses. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-TABLE)

> It can be used as a top-level command or as a space-saving syntax
> variant in parts of complex queries. Only the `WITH`, `UNION`, `INTERSECT`,
> `EXCEPT`, `ORDER BY`, `LIMIT`, `OFFSET`, `FETCH` and `FOR` locking clauses can be
> used with `TABLE`; the `WHERE` clause and any form of aggregation cannot
> be used.

Comment: Excellent, that's what I want. Thank you Erwin.

Comment: This saves a whopping 8 characters out of 13 ;)  Sigh, the important things they put in to the language.  Once again, your knowledge of Postgres shines.

Comment: According to Joe Celko (on the ANSI SQL board/committee for a decade) - a committee never saw an idea it didn't like...