# How do I pass in a table parameter to this function?

Tags: postgresql, casting, plpgsql

I have a function organized like so:

```
create function everything(waypoints waypoint)
  returns table(node int, xy text array) as $$
BEGIN
    create view results as ...

    return query (select * from results);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And I have a table that has arguments organized the way the `waypoint` data type is structured. This table is not explicitly of type `waypoint` itself.

The function gets created as it should, however, I am unable to call it by passing in my table like so:

`select everything(waypoints);`

Or `select everything(select * from temp);`

But it says syntax error at or near `select` for the latter and column `waypoints` does not exist for the former.

How do I proceed?

Comment: Why not make `everything` accept `temp` right away? `CREATE FUNCTION everything (waypoints temp) ...` and so on.

Comment: Please *always* provide your version of Postgres. Your question is a bit unclear. Do I understand correctly that you want to cast whole table rows to a pre-defined composite row type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything tested in Postgres **9.4**.

Postgres has some weak spots in the syntax for handling ROW types. You cannot cast from a table (alias) directly:

```
SELECT w::waypoint FROM waypoints w;
```

> ```
> ERROR:  cannot cast type waypoints to waypoint
> ```

The solution is only one step away: decompose the row in a subquery, then the cast works. This way, column values are decomposed and wrapped into the new type directly, without casting to `text` and back. No need to list all columns individually and you don't need to create a custom cast, either:

```
SELECT (w.*)::waypoint FROM (SELECT * FROM waypoints) w;
```

Or shorter:

```
SELECT w.*::waypoint FROM (TABLE waypoints) w;
```

Or shorter, yet:

```
SELECT w::waypoint FROM (TABLE waypoints) w;
```

- [Is there a shortcut for SELECT * FROM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275979/is-there-a-shortcut-for-select-from/30276023#30276023)

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/30281/1)

That's shorter and faster, in a quick test with 30k rows and simple types **10x faster** than casting to `text` and back. If you have (big) `jsonb` columns or any complex type (expensive conversion to/from `text`), the difference will be much bigger, yet.

More importantly, you don't *need* another custom composite (ROW) type. Every table already has its row defined as type automatically. Just use the existing type `waypoints` instead of `waypoint` (if at all possible). Then all you need is:

```
SELECT w FROM waypoints w;
```

Or, for your example:

```
SELECT everything(t) FROM temp t;  -- using type waypoints
SELECT everything(t::waypoint) FROM (TABLE temp) t;  -- using type waypoint
```

Asides:

- A table does not have "arguments" but columns.
- You are *not* passing a `table parameter to this function`, but rather a *row value*. That's how you pass a table by name:

  - [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

  You can't "pass a whole table" as parameter directly in Postgres, there are not table variables. You would use a cursor or a temp table for that.

#### Function

Your function has an invalid type declaration and is needlessly complex. I seriously doubt you want to create a view:

```
CREATE FUNCTION everything(_wp waypoint)  -- or use type waypoints
  RETURNS TABLE(node int, xy text[]) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT ...
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

`text array` is not valid syntax, using `text[]` instead to declare an array of `text`.

Rather not use the table  / type name `waypoints` as function parameter name, that opens you up to confusing errors.

Or just use a simple SQL function if your case is as simple as demonstrated:

```
CREATE FUNCTION everything(_wp waypoint)  -- or use type waypoints
  RETURNS TABLE(node int, xy text[]) AS
$func$
   SELECT ...
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Don't quote the language name. It's an identifier.

Comment: Hey this was an excellent write-up, much appreciated. However when I run this: `select everything(t.*::waypoint) from (table temp) t; I get: `relation "_wp" does not exist`... Why is this occuring?

Comment: @Louis93: `_wp` is the function parameter name in my example. Looks like dynamic SQL gone wrong. Since the function body is your secret, I can only guess. I suggest you post a *new question* with the necessary details.

Comment: I've awarded you the best answer because it is the most informative. Here is a new question with the necessary details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31188822/unable-to-drop-temp-table-is-postgres-function-because-it-is-being-used-by-act

Looking forward to your input.

Answer (score 1):

If all types in `waypoint` and `temp` are convertible to `text`, you can serialize to and deserialize from `text`:

```
SELECT  everything(temp::text::waypoint)
FROM    temp
```

However, an explicit construction would be cleaner:

```
SELECT  everything((col1, col2, col3, ...)::waypoint)
FROM    temp
```

or creating a `CAST`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION temp_to_waypoint (temp)
RETURNS waypoint
AS
$$
        SELECT  (col1, col2, col3, ...)::waypoint
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql';

CREATE CAST (temp AS waypoint) WITH FUNCTION temp_to_waypoint (test) AS IMPLICIT;

SELECT  everything(temp)
FROM    temp;
```

Comment: You mean temp::text::waypoint correct? Since waypoint is the datatype?

Comment: Another question, unrelated but I keep seeing this: 

cannot DROP TABLE "graph" because it is being used by active queries in this session

While this table is used to generate the results, it is created right after I attempt to drop it. How can I workaround this?

Comment: @Louis93: please post it as a separate question.