# Postgresql.. reorder rows based on "username" column alphabetically descendat

Tags: postgresql, view, sql-order-by, rows, descendant

I have a Postgresql 9.4.1 table, like this...

```
--------+-----------+-----------+----------------
serial  |  username |  userprod |  prodprice
--------+-----------+-----------+----------------
1       |  Zack     |  candy    |  44$
2       |  Tom      |  shoes    |  54$
3       |  Steve    |  pants    |  23$
4       |  Paul     |  hood     |  65$
5       |  John     |  cap      |  23$
6       |  Zack     |  tshirt   |  56$
7       |  Tom      |  pullover |  21$
8       |  Steve    |  socks    |  42$
9       |  Paul     |  shorts   |  23$
10      |  John     |  masc     |  21$
```

Rows are ordered by the serial column,
how can I display the same table but, reordering all the rows based on the "username" column alphabetically descending? I would like Postgres to do it automatically on real time on a separate table. I guess I can use View? How can I do that?

Comment: Read about `ORDER BY` clause: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Comment: Rows in a table are ***not*** "ordered". Any order you seen when not using `order by` is pure coincidence. If you want to see them ordered, use an `order by` when selecting. That is the ***only*** way to get a guaranteed order. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY

Comment: what about creating a view?? can that be done automatically??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use a [`VIEW`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createview.html) to return ordered rows.

```
CREATE VIEW v_tbl_username AS
TABLE tbl ORDER BY username;
```

And another one for your rows sorted by the `serial` column:

```
CREATE VIEW v_tbl_serial AS
TABLE tbl ORDER BY serial;
```

Read [@a_horse's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36958645/postgresql-reorder-rows-based-on-username-column-alphabetically-descendat#comment61478949_36958645) addressing your basic misconception.

The order holds unless it's overruled by another `ORDER BY` in the outer query.

Views work with `early binding`: Only columns present at the time of creation are included. `SELECT * FROM tbl` or [`TABLE tbl`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30276023/939860) are resolved to the list of currently existing column. If the underlying table is changed later, that's not cascaded to the view automatically.

Comment: thanks erwin, I knew I could use `SELECT * FROM tbl_
ORDER BY ircusername ASC, stmtserial ASC;` I just didn't know how to create it into a VIEW