# Return an empty table with N columns in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, function, common-table-expression

I have a Postgres function that RETURNS TABLE. I want to return an empty table in the event that a CTE has zero rows. Something like

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN (SELECT count(1) FROM mycte = 0) 
        THEN (SELECT ... ??) -- not sure what to put here to return zero rows
        ELSE (SELECT ...)    -- A normal database query
        END)
```

How can I accomplish this? Just writing `SELECT` with nothing else returns a single column. `SELECT x, y FROM ()` doesn't work. `SELECT (SELECT , SELECT)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

If by "empty table" you mean *no row*, then just do not return anything.

In PL/pgSQL functions, just don't do anything (or execute a single `RETURN;`).

In SQL functions, add `WHERE false` or `LIMIT 0` to your `SELECT`, so that no row is returned. Like:

```
SELECT -- your "ELSE" stuff here
WHERE  EXISTS (TABLE mycte);
```

Counting would be more expensive than `EXISTS`.
`TABLE mycte` is short for `SELECT * FROM mycte`. See:

- [Is there a shortcut for SELECT * FROM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275979/is-there-a-shortcut-for-select-from/30276023#30276023)

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT c1
  FROM t1
)
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM cte) -- Only return rows from outer query if there are rows in your cte "table"
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/61913/15