# How convert recursive to function in plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, recursive-query

i have that working code, but i need to convert it to function with dynamic attribute `tid=1645` where number 1645 will always change.

```
with recursive r as (
    select tid, boss from titles where tid=1645
    union
    select titles.tid, titles.boss from titles join r on titles.tid = r.boss
)
select * from r
```

Now, i have the same:

```
DROP FUNCTION bosses_of_rsd_tids(integer);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.bosses_of_rsd_tids(rsd_tid int)
    RETURNS table (c_tid int, c_boss int)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    begin
        with recursive r as (
            select tid, boss from titles where tid=rsd_tid
            union
            select titles.tid, titles.boss from titles join r on titles.boss = r.tid
        )

        select c_tid, c_boss;
    end;
 $function$
;
```

As a result i need table of results... I tried to `return select c_tid, c_boss;` but have error: error near return

Comment: RETURN QUERY WITH RECURSIVE R ...?

Comment: @S-Man no, have error near end

Comment: What is it you want to return.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe the tree of employee. two columns: one is your number, the other is the number of the boss. I need to get the entire hierarchy by the parameter

Comment: Then follow @S-Man's advice. Add the error you get, plus your updated code, to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.bosses_of_rsd_tids(rsd_tid int)
  RETURNS TABLE (c_tid int, c_boss int) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
      SELECT tid, boss
      FROM   titles
      WHERE  tid = rsd_tid

      UNION ALL                           -- ?!
      SELECT t.tid, t.boss
      FROM   r
      JOIN   titles t ON t.tid = r.boss   -- !
      )
   TABLE r;                               -- !
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You want `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` as it doesn't make sense to try and fold duplicates climbing the hierarchy. (A duplicate would initiate an endless loop.)

`TABLE r` is short for `SELECT * FROM r`. Your org. `select c_tid, c_boss` was wrong. See:

- [Is there a shortcut for SELECT * FROM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275979/is-there-a-shortcut-for-select-from/30276023#30276023)

Can also be a simpler SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.bosses_of_rsd_tids(rsd_tid int)
  RETURNS TABLE (c_tid int, c_boss int) AS
$func$
   WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
      SELECT tid, boss
      FROM   titles
      WHERE  tid = rsd_tid

      UNION ALL
      SELECT t.tid, t.boss
      FROM   r
      JOIN   titles t ON t.tid = r.boss
      )
   TABLE r;
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

See:

- [Difference between language sql and language plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/difference-between-language-sql-and-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions/24771561#24771561)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use "return query" on all the query (with included)

You forgot the "from r" in the main select

/* EDIT */
 in you example you select c_tid and c_boss instead of tid and boss
  and the test of the join is inverted

request updated:

```
  DROP FUNCTION bosses_of_rsd_tids(integer);
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.bosses_of_rsd_tids(rsd_tid int)
   RETURNS table (c_tid int, c_boss int)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
 AS $function$
    begin
       return query with recursive r as (
        select tid, boss from titles where tid=rsd_tid
        union
        select titles.tid, titles.boss from titles join r on titles.tid = r.boss        )

    select tid, boss from r;
end;
$function$
;
```

Comment: In the second case (worked) a strange result is issued. If no function is used, then the values `1645 15169; 15169 1731; 1731 13602; 13602 NULL`, and if the first, then a huge number of entries. No function - right