# Group by multiple columns and get result as an array in separate columns

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate

I have a table like the following:

```
| col_A | col_B |
|-------|-------|
| 1     | 1     |
| 1     | 2     |
| 1     | 3     |
| 2     | 1     |
| 2     | 2     |
| 2     | 3     |
| 3     | 1     |
| 3     | 2     |
```

I want to group and concatenate the results into an array like the following:

```
| col_A | col_B |
|-------|-------|
| 1,2   | 1,2,3 |
| 3     |  1,2  |
```

My attempt at writing a query:

`SELECT col_A, array_agg(col_B ORDER BY col_B DESC) FROM table GROUP BY col_A;`

However, this outputs:

```
| col_A | col_B   |
|-------|---------|
| 1     | {1,2,3} |
| 2     | {1,2,3} |
| 3     | {1,2}   |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you want to aggregate `col_b` grouped by `col_a`, and then aggregate `col_a` grouped by the aggregated arrays. You can do this with a nested query, of which you did the first step already:

```
SELECT array_agg(col_a), col_b
FROM (SELECT col_a, array_agg(DISTINCT col_b ORDER BY col_b) AS col_b
      FROM example GROUP BY col_a) grouped_b
GROUP BY col_b;
```

([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=168beb8f6bf43d62a6f91f3ce53da145))

Comment: You might want to remove the `DISTINCT` from the aggregate, not sure whether you need/want that.

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, ordering rows in a subquery is typically cheaper than adding an `ORDER BY` clause to the aggregate function:

```
SELECT array_agg(col_a) AS col_a, col_b
FROM  (
   SELECT col_a, array_agg(col_b) AS col_b
   FROM  (TABLE tbl ORDER BY col_a, col_b) t
   GROUP  BY 1
   ORDER  BY 1
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 2
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Produces your desired result exactly, including order of elements and rows.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=023c4816d05fa52c97bbfc071f08ef8c)*

The 1st `ORDER BY` is to sort elements before constructing the array in `col_b`.
The 2nd `ORDER BY` is to sort elements before constructing the array in `col_a`.
The 3rd `ORDER BY` is to output rows in the order suggested by the OPs example result.

The query *should* work the same without 2nd and 3rd `ORDER BY`, because the 1st order is carried over. But there are no guarantees. (Things like parallelism might mess with order when querying big tables.) The presented query is *guaranteed* to produce the desired order.

Related:

- [Is it REALLY possible that the order will not be guaranteed for this particular redundant derived table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/185862/3684)

About the positional references in `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [Concatenate multiple result rows of one column into one, group by another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847173/concatenate-multiple-result-rows-of-one-column-into-one-group-by-another-column/15850510#15850510)

About `(TABLE tbl ORDER BY col_a, col_b)`:

- [Is there a shortcut for SELECT * FROM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275979/is-there-a-shortcut-for-select-from/30276023#30276023)

Comment: What is this `GROUP BY 1` and `ORDER BY 2` syntax, does that refer to the column indices? And why exactly do you sort them at all (apart from ensuring that the array elements will have the same order in the outer grouping comparison)?

Comment: @Bergi: I added a link to explain positional references. And explanation for each `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Thanks, I had never seen ordinal numbers to refer to columns. Makes sense though!

Comment: @Bergi: I used them here to avoid more typing. Whether it's easier to read & maintain is a matter of debate. Most useful to avoid repeating lengthy expressions or with dynamic SQL.