# Best way to get distinct count from a query joining two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, postgresql-performance, postgres-9.6

I have 2 tables, table `A` & table `B`.

Table `A` (has thousands of rows)

- id
- uuid
- name
- type
- created_by
- org_id

Table `B` (has a max of hundred rows)

- org_id
- org_name

I am trying to get the best join query to obtain a count with a `WHERE` clause. I need the count of distinct `created_by`s from table `A` with an `org_name` in Table `B` that contains 'myorg'. I currently have the below query (producing expected results) and wonder if this can be optimized further?

```
select count(distinct a.created_by)
from a left join
     b
     on a.org_id = b.org_id 
where b.org_name like '%myorg%';
```

Comment: Please don't change the question after answers have been given. Start a new question instead. I rolled back your change, you can find everything in the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61028864/revisions).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, sure! [new q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61037164/best-way-to-get-distinct-count-from-a-query-joining-two-tables-multiple-join-po)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `left join`:

```
select count(distinct a.created_by)
from a join
     b
     on a.org_id = b.org_id
where b.org_name like '%myorg%'
```

For this query, you want an index on `b.org_id`, which I assume that you have.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `exists` for this:

```
select count(distinct a.created_by)
from a
where exists (select 1 from b where b.org_id = a.org_id and b.org_name like '%myorg%')
```

An index on `b(org_id)` would help. But in terms of performance, key points are:

- searching using `like` with a wildcard on both sides is not good for performance (this cannot take advantage of an index); it would be far better to search for an exact match, or at least to not have a wildcard on the left side of the string.
- `count(distinct ...)` is more expensive than a regular `count()`; if you don't *really* need `distinct`, then don't use it.

Comment: `like` is applied in table `b` with max 100 rows, so hardly relevant to performance in this particular case. In other cases, a trigram index can be used: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452528/939860

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks good already. Use a plain `[INNER] JOIN` instead or `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`, like Gordon suggested. But that won't change much.

You mention that table `B` has only ...

> a max of hundred rows

while table `A` has ...

> thousands of rows

***If*** there are many rows per `created_by` (which I'd expect), then there is potential for an [*emulated* index skip scan](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan).
(The need to emulate it might go away [in one of the coming Postgres versions](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/19/1741/).)

**Essential** ingredient is this **multicolumn index**:

```
CREATE INDEX ON a (org_id, created_by);
```

It can *replace* a simple index on just `(org_id)` and works for your simple query as well. See:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

There are two complications for your case:

1. `DISTINCT`
2. 0-n `org_id` resulting from `org_name like '%myorg%'`

So the optimization is harder to implement. But still possible with some fancy SQL:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT created_by)  -- does not count NULL (as desired)
FROM   b
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
      (  -- parentheses required
      SELECT created_by
      FROM   a
      WHERE  org_id = b.org_id
      ORDER  BY created_by
      LIMIT 1
      )
      UNION ALL
      SELECT (SELECT created_by
              FROM   a
              WHERE  org_id = b.org_id
              AND    created_by > t.created_by
              ORDER  BY created_by
              LIMIT  1)
      FROM   t
      WHERE  t.created_by IS NOT NULL  -- stop recursion
      )
   TABLE t
   ) a
WHERE  b.org_name LIKE '%myorg%';
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7ac8fdcc2cf85e4df986051ed344a77f)* (Postgres 12, but works in Postgres 9.6 as well.)

That's a [recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) in a `LATERAL` subquery, using a correlated subquery.

It utilizes the multicolumn index from above to only retrieve a *single* row for every `(org_id, created_by)`. With an index-only scans if the table is vacuumed enough.

The main **objective** of the sophisticated SQL is to completely avoid a sequential scan (or even a bitmap index scan) on the big table and only read very few fast index tuples.

Due to the added overhead it can be a bit slower for an unfavorable data distribution (*many* `org_id` and/or only *few* rows per `created_by`) But it's ***much*** faster for favorable conditions and is scales excellently, even for millions of rows. You'll have to test to find the sweet spot.

Related:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)
- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)
- [Is there a shortcut for SELECT * FROM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275979/is-there-a-shortcut-for-select-from/30276023#30276023)