# Best way to get distinct count from a query joining two tables (multiple join possibilities)

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-performance

I have 2 tables, table `Actions` & table `Users`. `Actions` -> `Users` is `many-one` association.

Table `Actions` (has thousands of rows)

- id
- uuid
- name
- type
- created_by
- org_id

Table `Users` (has a max of hundred rows)

- id
- username
- org_id
- org_name

I am trying to get the best join query to obtain a count with a `WHERE` clause. I need the count of distinct `created_by`s from table `Actions` with an `org_name` in Table `Users` that contains 'myorg'. Also, (`Actions.created_by` = `Users.username`)

I currently have the below queries (producing expected results) and wonder which is better and if it can be optimized further?

Query 1:

```
select count(distinct Actions.created_by)
from Actions join
     Users
     on Users.org_id = Actions.org_id 
where Users.org_name like '%myorg%';
```

Query 2:

```
select count(distinct Users.username)
from Users join
     Actions
     on Actions.created_by = Users.username 
where Users.org_name like '%myorg%';
```

Comment: The two queries produce different results.  You should use the one that does what you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, updated queries, these 2 always produce the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest approach is to modify the second query:

```
select count(*)
from Users u
where exists (select 1
              from Actions a
              where a.created_by = u.username 
             )
and u.org_name like '%myorg%';
```

Then the best index is on `actions(created_by)`.