# What happens when you insert rows in a SERIAL column with existing values?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I had to import a large CSV file into a database, and one column must be a unique ID for a purchase. I set the type of the column to `SERIAL` (yes, I know it's not actually a type) but since I already had some data in there with their own "random" purchase IDs I'm not sure about what will happen when I insert new rows.

Will the purchase ID take the values that are not already in use? Will it start after the biggest existing ID? Will it start at 1 and not care about if a value is already in use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying `SEQUENCE` will not care about the values you inserted (explicitly providing values for the `serial` column, overruling the default), you have to adapt manually to avoid duplicate key errors:

```
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('tbl', 'id'), max(id)) FROM tbl;
```

`'tbl'` and `'id'` being the names of table and column respectively.
Related:

- [How to reset postgres' primary key sequence when it falls out of sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync/23390399#23390399)
- [How to copy both structure and contents of PostgreSQL table, but duplicate sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264719/how-to-copy-both-structure-and-contents-of-postgresql-table-but-duplicate-seque/12265248#12265248)