# SQLAlchemy primary key assignement

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm wondering where in the process of creating objects and storing them in the database the primary key gets assigned by SQLAlchemy. In my app, when something happens I create an Event for that 'happening' and then create a notification for each user that needs to know about that Event. This all happens in the same method.

The problem now is that the Notification references the Event. Should I connect twice to the database to achieve this? First to store the Event so it gets assigned a primary key and secondly to store the notification? 
Is it possible to only connect once to the database?

So these steps should happen:

1. User does something
2. Create an Event
3. **Necessary?** Store the Event in the database so I get a primary key to reference to
4. Create a Notification that references the Event
5. Store the Notification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to worry about the primary-key to create the `Notification` just pass the `Event` object to the `Notification`, and `commit`. You're good to go.

SQLAlchemy doesn't assign the primary-key, it is the database that usually and implicitly [does it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698521/set-sqlalchemy-to-use-postgresql-serial-for-identity-generation) for you, provided you have declared the table with something like this: `id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)`.

```
class Event(Base):
    __tablename__ = "events"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    ...

class Notification(Base):
    __tablename__ = "notifications"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    event_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("events.id"))
    event = relationship("Event")
    ...
    def __init__(self, event):
        self.event = event


notification = Notification(Event())
session.add(notification)
session.commit()
```

Comment: I imagine it should be: event = relationship("Event") ? :)

Comment: ahh..good catch. Also it should be `event_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("event.id"))`. Fixed

Comment: uh I think it should be events.id though