# unique elements in sql-alchemy selection with condition

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table called votes which stores votes made by users. The table stores the user_id, a group_id, a timestamp of the vote and the item_id for what the user voted for:

```
votes
------------
user_id
group_id
item_id
vote_datetime
```

The way I setup the table means that users can vote for the same item multiple times, and the only difference between these votes would be the datetime.

My question is how can I select all elements of that table with the same group_id, but with the condition to count only one vote per user for an item?
thanks in advance
carl

EDIT: Here is a start.

select all elements for group_id equal 1

allvotes = models.votes.query.filter_by(group_id=1).all()

so how would I modify this to make sure that users can't vote twice for the same item?

Comment: do you need a generic sql solution for this?

Comment: no a sql-alchemy statement would be good... I will give it a start in an edit above in a sec

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLAlchemy primary key assignement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735495/sqlalchemy-primary-key-assignement)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign primary key on combination of (user, group, item) like this:

```
user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
group_id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
item_id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
```

If you want just to query unique votes, use aggregate function with group:

```
query(user_id, group_id, item_id, func.min(vote_datetime)).
group_by(User_id, group_id, item_id)
```

Above should be close to the syntax you need.

Comment: Hi Bulat, I don't quite understand how this solves my problem?

Comment: It will not allow the duplication of user vote per item  within a group, which means 'that users can't vote twice'. Or that was not the question?

Comment: no I want users to vote multiple times, I just need to know how to select samples in which I only have unique votes. E.g. just pick the first vote with the corresponding group_id and user_id...

Comment: I guess you need to rephrase your question to make it more clear.

Comment: I have updated the answer, basically you need to group by results by user, group, item and get the min value for datetime.