# SQLAlchemy not setting primary key from auto increment after commit

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using `SQLAlchemy` to connect to a postgresql database. I have defined my primary key columns in postgresql to be of type `serial` i.e. auto-increment integer and have marked them in my `SQLAlchemy` model with `primary_key=true`.

On committing the `SQLAlchemy` session, the model is saved to the db and I can see the primary key set in the database but the `id` property on my `SQLAlchemy` model object always has a value of `None` i.e. it isn't picking up the auto-increment value. I'm not sure what I have got wrong.

I have checked out the existing SO questions but have not found an answer:

- [Set SQLAlchemy to use PostgreSQL SERIAL for identity generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698521/set-sqlalchemy-to-use-postgresql-serial-for-identity-generation)
- [sqlalchemy flush() and get inserted id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316952/sqlalchemy-flush-and-get-inserted-id)

My code is below:

Create the table in postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE my_model
(
    id serial NOT NULL,
    type text,
    user_id integer,

    CONSTRAINT pk_network_task PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Set up SQLAlchemy and the model:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

engine = create_engine(db_url, convert_unicode=True, echo=True)
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine))

class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_model'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer)
    type = sa.Column(sa.String)
```

Try and store the model:

```
my_model = MyModel()
user_id = 1
type = "A type"
session.merge(my_model)
session.commit()
my_model.id #Always None, don't know why
```

`my_model.id` is still `None` after the commit. I have also try calling `close` on the session but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out I didn't understand the difference between

```
session.merge(my_model)
```

and

```
session.add(my_model)
```

`session.merge(my_model)` (which I had been using) doesn't add the object given to it to the session. Instead it returns a new object i.e. the merged model, which has been added to the session. If you reference this new object all is well i.e.

```
my_model = session.merge(my_model)
```

`add` on the other hand, adds the object given to it to the session.