# hibernate persist fails tries to create object with existing id

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

I am using spring-hibernate-postgres. I have a table say 'some_entity'. It already contains some records.

I have a program that tries to create new SomeEntity object. I am populating that object with appropriate properties, and afterwards I am calling persist() method on it.

In the log, I see that hibernate is trying to get nextVal() from the table sequences. But, nextval that my postgres returns is same as id of 2nd row of some_entity table. So, my hibernate tries to create row with that id. And hence my persist() fails with hibernate constraint violation exception.

May be I am not phrasing the question correctly. I hope someone has already encountered this problem and has resolution for it.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds as though your sequence is out of sync with your tables? Could this help - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. I solved it through execution of sql, that updates sequence at application launch

```
ALTER SEQUENCE names_id_seq RESTART WITH currentId;
```

,where currentId I get from

```
SELECT currval('names_id_seq');
```