# How to see where postgresql sequence is at in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have experienced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028997/activerecord-raising-duplicate-key-error-on-simple-create) issue of rails auto-increment falling out of sync with the app's postgresql sequence. This happened because I manually added records and gave them an ID, which meant those records had ID's but postgresql sequence didn't know about those records and so didn't augment the postgresql sequence, so the sequence didn't change and this caused major issues later.

In any case, I have a simple question, is there a command I can run to find out where the postgresql sequence is at for a particular table? Most the time it will (hopefully) be the same value as the last max id in that table, but I want to do some exploring/checking, and thus want to know how to find where the sequence is at.

#### Note

I tried

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('users', 'id'));")
```

And it returned

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):4
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::ObjectNotInPrerequisiteState: ERROR:  currval of sequence "users_id_seq" is not yet defined in this session)
: select currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('users', 'id'));
```

#### Also Note

I ran (similar to above)

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('users', 'id'));")
```

And it returns

```
=> #<PG::Result:0x000000000521ce88 status=PGRES_TUPLES_OK ntuples=1 nfields=1 cmd_tuples=1>
```

But I would expect to see a number. E.g. if the `users` table has 6000 users, I would expect it to return `6001` (the next in sequence)

Answer (score 1):

This will return the current value of the sequence (for the `users` table - to do it for a different table, just replace 'users' below with your table name)

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT currval('users_id_seq');").values
```