# Rails: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Here is the error when saving a record into postgres database on rails 3.2.12 & pg 9.3:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
: INSERT INTO "sw_module_infox_module_infos" ("about_controller", "about_init", "about_log", "about_misc_def", "about_model", "about_onboard_data", "about_subaction", "about_view", "about_workflow", "active", "api_spec", "category_id", "created_at", "last_updated_by_id", "module_desp", "name", "submit_date", "submitted_by_id", "updated_at", "version", "wf_state") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21) RETURNING "id"):
  activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1166:in `get_last_result'
  activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1166:in `exec_cache'
```

The table was working fine until now (saved about 50 records before the error today). After opening the pg table in pgadmin. we found the `id` on the table is `integer`. We also found `Id` on other table is `serial`. It seems that the id should be `serial` so it can auto-increment. If it is, then how to convert a id column to `serial` from `integer`? If it is not, then how to fix this problem?

Comment: "serial" is just an alias for `INTEGER` with a `DEFAULT nextval('some_sequence')` ; see the user manual.

Comment: Table was created with rails rake db:migrate. About 8 out of 33 tables have integer type. The rest is serial. Some tables are missing index as well. Not sure what caused the problem with postgres. The same table created by sqlite has no such problem at all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> The data types [`smallserial`, `serial` and `bigserial`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) are not true types, but merely a notational convenience for creating unique identifier columns (similar to the `AUTO_INCREMENT` property supported by some other databases).

If your column is an `integer`, you cannot *convert* it to `serial`, but you can mimic, what PostgreSQL would have done, just like you created your table with a serial:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq;
ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN colname SET DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq'::regclass);
ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq OWNED BY tablename.colname;
```

Comment: What could caused the problem? The same migrations have been used with sqlite and never have such problem. About 8 out of 33 tables has id as integer (not serial). Also some of them are missing index as well. It starts bothering us because we don't know why it happened with postgres. We thought postgres was more robust than sqlite.

Comment: @user938363 again, serial is not a true type. All of your columns are `integer` (in PgAdmin, you can check it on its *Properties* > *Data Type*). The difference between your columns are just the default values & the existence of their sequences. -- There must be some difference between these table's definition in ruby, so rails decided not to build them like serials, but that should be a different question (& mainly rails / rake related)

Comment: @@pozs, do we need to set sequence to next available id? Or the 3 commands above have done that.

Comment: @user938363 this will only fix the structures, if you'll have troubles with your values too, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync

Answer (score 8):

I had an issue like this when working on a Rails 6 application.

I had a **User** model that is used to create a `student` and an `admin`:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :role
end
```

And a **Role** model:

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
end
```

However, I wanted the `admin` and `student` roles to be assigned for each `admin` and `student` respectively when they are created **without having a roles field in the forms**, so my  models were like this:

The **Admin** model:

```
class Admin < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :set_admin_role

  belongs_to :user

  private

  def set_admin_role
    # set role_id to '1' except if role_id is not empty
    user.role_id = '1' if user.role_id.nil?
  end
end
```

The **Student** model:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :set_student_role

  belongs_to :user

  private

  def set_student_role
    # set role_id to '2' except if role_id is not empty
    user.role_id = '2' if user.role_id.nil?
  end
end
```

So this was throwing errors whenever I tried creating admins and students:

```
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "role_id" violates not-null constraint)
```

**Here's how I solved it**:

The issue was that the `role_id` in the `users` table was set to `null: false` in my migration file. I had to change it to `null: true`:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest
      t.references :role, null: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And then also changed the **User** model, to have the `role_id` as optional:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :role, optional: true
end
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: This is perfectly documented and exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you for saving me hours!

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem.

I'll tell what was wrong, maybe someone will find my experience useful

> I had `ERROR:  null value in column "created_at" violates not-null constraint`

and the problem was that I had a methods that ran in `before_create` and `before_save` and this methods tried to save with minor updates. So it tried to save few times.

> My suggestion is to check what your code is doing in `before_save`
> and `before_create`

Answer (score 0):

Just add  `optional: true` to the model which we have to map

example:

user :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :tasks
end
```

task:

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user, optional: true

end

set ----->  null: true , in ur DB/migration/
```