# How to insert json data into my table using postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsp, servlets

i have a clients table with 2 columns

```
CREATE TABLE clients
(
    client_id    serial primary key,
    name        VARCHAR(40) not null
)
```

i have a json data like

```
[{client_id:"1",name:"Rick"},{client_id:"2",name:"Carlin"}]
```

Now i need to use this json to parse and insert into my client table. How can i do it using **jsp servlets** and **postgres database**.

Comment: have you looked at http://yetanotherdataminer.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/how-to-get-json-data-type-into.html which gives details on how to load JSON data into a single string per row, then transform?

Comment: Also, what version of postgres are you using, as 9.2 added support for JSON inside the DB, and 9.3 added extra functionality for dealing with JSON data.

Comment: And ... what have you tried and where are you stuck ?

Comment: @mc110: i am using postgres 9.1.2 which doesnt support this functionality

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Jsp page gets this data from  client through form which converted into json and passed to the servlet. Now servlet has to insert the data into the database

Comment: And where occurs the encoding in json ? javascript in browser ? servlet ? jsp ? Or is it only to allow a rest API ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Encoding into json occurs in a function toJson() to which a call from servlet is made in doGet() function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do it on PostgreSQL (9.3+) side, you can use the [`json_populate_recordset`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) function:

```
insert into clients
select *
from json_populate_recordset(
  null::clients,
  '[{client_id:"1",name:"Rick"},{client_id:"2",name:"Carlin"}]'
)
```

Although, [that's usually not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync) to manually insert values to a serial column.