# Error creating new content types. Please make sure contenttypes is migrated before trying to migrate apps individually

Tags: django, migration, django-south, django-1.8

I am trying to migrate from `Django 1.6` to `Django 1.8`. I was using `South` for managing `migrations` in Django 1.6. I have successfully created new migration files by `python manage.py makemigrations`. while running `python manage.py migrate --fake-initial`, I am getting this error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 39, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/jonty/.virtualenvs/squadrun/local/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in   execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/jonty/.virtualenvs/squadrun/local/lib/python2.7/site-  packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/jonty/.virtualenvs/squadrun/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/jonty/.virtualenvs/squadrun/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/jonty/.virtualenvs/squadrun/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 225, in handle
    emit_post_migrate_signal(created_models, self.verbosity, self.interactive, connection.alias)
  File "/home/jonty/.virtualenvs/squadrun/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 280, in emit_post_migrate_signal
using=db)
  File "/home/jonty/.virtualenvs/squadrun/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 201, in send
response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/home/jonty/.virtualenvs/squadrun/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 82, in create_permissions
    ctype = ContentType.objects.db_manager(using).get_for_model(klass)
  File "/home/jonty/.virtualenvs/squadrun/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 78, in get_for_model
    "Error creating new content types. Please make sure contenttypes "
```

One of the migration file `0001_initial.py` says:

```
dependencies = [
    ('auth', '0006_require_contenttypes_0002'),
    ('clients', '0002_auto_20150428_1551'),
    ('players', '0001_initial'),
]
```

which I guess is particularly the problem. What could be the workaround this problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The dependency on auth 0006 should ensure that `contenttypes` is migrated before the post migration signal is run. What's the error if you manually run `ContentType.objects.get(app_label=<app label>, model_name=<model name>)`?

Comment: `ContentType matching query does not exist`

Comment: And with `get_or_create()`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I think this has something to do with "The removal of `ContentType.name`", according to [this](https://github.com/django/django/commit/b4ac23290772e0c11379eb2dfb81c750b7052b66). But somehow it doesnt work.

By manually removing the column `name` from 'django_content_type' table. Eg.

`'ALTER TABLE django_content_type DROP COLUMN name'`

I was able to apply the migrations. Maybe this can get you a little bit further at least.

Comment: I was able to make this work by completly deleting the table `django_content_type` and running the migration. Yeah and it's because the `name` has been removed in `Django 1.8`.

Comment: Another option, create a temporary database, do a syncdb etc., then copy the django_content_type table into the problem database.

Comment: There is `django/contrib/contenttypes/migrations/0002_remove_content_type_name.py` in Django 1.8. Didn't check when it was added.

Comment: @Shubham Interestingly, I dropped the table as well and yet the error persists. `:/`

Answer (score 18):

Try to migrate auth application first, and then others:

```
manage.py migrate auth
manage.py migrate <app_name>
```

Comment: @Stryker I'm so glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 7):

In my case, what i did to fix this was updating to a newer version of django. 
If you work with mac just do:

1. pip install django --upgrade
2. python manage.py makemigrations
3. python manage.py migrate

Answer (score 3):

May look strange but I fixed this by upgrading to Django version 1.8.
Initially i was using ver 1.7

Comment: Upgrading to a newer version did solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To add to comment by @int_ua
Add this as a dependency to the migration that is failing:

```
dependencies = [
    ('contenttypes', '0002_remove_content_type_name'),
]
```

Then run migration again.

Answer (score 2):

I had to merge two systems in Django 1.9.1 and I just could not get past this error:

```
 "Error creating new content types. Please make sure contenttypes "
```

Extensive googling and stackoverflowing was fruitless. Finally, I added the the debug line to

~/.virtualenvs/(venv_name)/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py

```
 except (OperationalError, ProgrammingError, IntegrityError):
        # It's possible to migrate a single app before contenttypes,
        # as it's not a required initial dependency (it's contrib!)
        # Have a nice error for this.
        print "\n\nError for Content type model "+opts.model_name+"\n\n"
        raise RuntimeError(
            "Error creating new content types. Please make sure contenttypes "
            "is migrated before trying to migrate apps individually."
        )
```

This told me the model names that were causing the error and ultimately led to the fix.

I am using Postgres and the sequence numbers for tables django_content_type and auth_permission were not pointing to the end of the table, causing inserts to fail.

These 2 lines fixed that (based on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23390399/615379))

```
SELECT pg_catalog.setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('django_content_type', 'id'), (SELECT MAX(id) FROM django_content_type)+1);
SELECT pg_catalog.setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('auth_permission', 'id'), (SELECT MAX(id) FROM auth_permission)+1);
```