# Wt DBO + Duplicate Key error

Tags: postgresql, wt

I was trying to find a solution for the key duplication error in Wt::Dbo + PostgreSQL. I have seen many forums about this error, but didn't find a fix for Wt alone.

It will be really help full if somebody can provide a solution for the above problem.

Regards
Ansif

Answer (score 0):

I have applied the fix from the below link, [How to reset postgres' primary key sequence when it falls out of sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync)

In Wt, we have to do something like this.
dbo::Query< dbo::ptr > query = session.query < dbo::ptr >
        ("SELECT setval(\"Tblname_id_seq\", COALESCE((SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM \"Tablename\"), 1), false)");

dbo::ptr newRecord = session.add(new Tablename());

Regards
Ansif