# while trying to create object it's not using new id

Tags: python, flask, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a `User` `Model`.

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
```

I created this table in the database and I had some users which I exported from old database and loaded this in this new table via insert query.
but now when I try to create user using ORM like below

```
user = User(name="sanjay")
db.session.add(user)
db.session.commit()
```

it's throwing below error.

```
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists
```

because a user with id 1 is already present in the table, so sqlalchemy should try to create a new record with latest id.

can someone help here?

Comment: For that u will need to set autoincrement,  try this ```db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)``` & make sure you enable the same in db table also.

Comment: I tried with autoincrement also, but still same

Comment: Which DB your using ?

Comment: I am using Postgres

Comment: U might need to update the autoincrement start value, https://kylewbanks.com/blog/Adding-or-Modifying-a-PostgreSQL-Sequence-Auto-Increment

Comment: The sequence supplying the default primary key value does not track if you insert values manually in the table. It has to be updated to produce values that do not overlap with those inserted. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40280158/postgres-sqlalchemy-auto-increment-not-working/40281835#40281835