# Prisma postgres - Unique constraint failed on the fields: (`id`)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prisma

For some reason I'm getting the error `Unique constraint failed on the fields: (`id`)`  when trying to create a new Artist document.

Below is the function I'm calling.

```
async create(createArtistInput: CreateArtistInput): Promise<Artist> {
    console.log(createArtistInput, 'create artist input')
    const slug = slugify(createArtistInput.name, {
      replacement: '-',
      strict: true,
    })
    return this.db.artist.create({
      data: {
        name: createArtistInput.name,
        spotifyArtistId: createArtistInput.spotifyArtistId,
        spotifyArtistName: createArtistInput.spotifyArtistName,
        slug,
      },
    })
  }
```

The console log prints the following response, so I don't understand why the unique constraint of **id** is failing, as I'm not passing one in. I'm letting the prisma schema handle that.

```
{
  name: 'twofiveone',
  spotifyArtistId: '5Fex9xz9rkPqQqMBVtuIrE',
  spotifyArtistName: 'twofiveone'
} create artist input
```

Here is the prisma schema if needed

```
model Artist {
  id                Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name              String
  slug              String?
  createdAt         DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt         DateTime @updatedAt
  spotifyArtistId   String?
  spotifyArtistName String?
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what is happening? It's as if I can't create and new artists for some reason.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

Autoincrement creates its own sequence starting from 1 which you can read more about [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-serial/).

If you add random records with the id, then Postgres doesn't know that and it tries to start from 1. If 1 is already present, then it will throw an error.

So the best practice, in this case, is always let the database generate the id for you instead of you adding it manually. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for this is that somehow rows have been manually added with the id 0 at the start.

Answer (score 0):

In case you've imported tables from other db, you might want to fix the autoincrement see here:
[PostgreSQL: Unique violation: 7 ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_pkey"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37970743/postgresql-unique-violation-7-error-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-const/37972960#37972960)

As pointed out in the answer you can run for every tables

`SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"MyTable"', 'id'), coalesce(max(id)+1, 1), false) FROM "MyTable";`