# Rails active record seems out of sync with postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-7

I am using `rails 7` and `postgres 14.5` and active record now seems out of sync with postgres.

I saved a `user` and I got `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_pkey" DETAIL:  Key (id)=(3) already exists. ):`

From [PostgreSQL: Unique violation: 7 ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_pkey"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37970743/postgresql-unique-violation-7-error-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-const), I ran `SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('users', 'id'), coalesce(max(id)+1, 1), false) FROM users;`  which seemed to fix that initial issue and allowed me to save the user.

Then I destroyed the user and tried to save the user again and now I'm getting `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_users_on_email" DETAIL:  Key (email)=(test@test.com) already exists. ):`

This is telling me that my active record is out of sync with my postgres.

Any ideas on how I can fix this out of sync issue or at least fix the index issue now?

Comment: Those errors are being returned by the database meaning the database is returning error code 23505 resulting in the error message you are seeing. [PG::UniqueViolation](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/blob/master/ext/errorcodes.def#L391). You can reset the primary key sequence for the table via `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!('table_name')` but the second error means that email already exists and you should look at the data in the database.

Comment: Could you provide more context as to when you are getting these errors? Are they in a testing suite where maybe you have set things up incorrectly and you are incidentally creating your own collisions, perhaps?