# What s wrong with the syntax of this SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence(‘tags’, ‘id’), SELECT max(id) FROM tags);
```

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3698777/1073631

Comment: Using PostgreSQL inside rails. I am trying to correct it to execute inActiveRecords. I am not an expert in SQL. How would you correct it please ?

Comment: Moussa, @sgeddes, have already provided the answer to you by linking the other similar post. Go through it and change your query accordingly

Comment: Yes, I realize that. Thanks a lot guys !!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset postgres' primary key sequence when it falls out of sync?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using curly quotes `‘’` while you should be using straight quotes `''`:

```
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('tags', 'id'), SELECT max(id) FROM tags);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the code you intend:

```
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('tags', 'id'), maxid)
FROM ( SELECT max(id) as maxid FROM tags) t;
```