# Postgresql error: insert operation returns id exists in Python

Tags: python, postgresql

**I tried to insert `name` into database.**

```
name = 'test'
cur.execute("INSERT INTO scholars(name) VALUES('{}') returning id".format(name))
id = cur.fetchone()
print(id)
```

**error message:**

```
psycopg2.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "idx_16514_primary"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2321) already exists.
```

When `id=2301`, it succeed,and return ID.
After that,`id += 1`and returns the error below.

http://ob9j09f06.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-10-12-16%3A31%3A12.jpg

Comment: Did you insert values manually without updating the sequence properly?

Comment: There might be something wrong with your id sequence, run `SELECT currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('scholars', 'id'));` to show the most recent value created by id sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that You already have record with ID 2321 in your DB. Can You check with `SELECT id FROM scholars`?

Comment: But it should be manually add id when i insert a new data.

Comment: My guess: You have deleted some records, or You have manually created some IDs, so automatic generator got into problems.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @e4c5, @kxxoling

Here i got the answer [How to reset postgres' primary key sequence when it falls out of sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync) to this question.

Something was wrong with my `id sequence`.

I fixed it by doing this.

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM scholars;
```

=> 11518

```
SELECT nextval('scholars_id_seq');
```

=> 2324 # here it is lower than max(id)

```
SELECT setval('scholars_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM scholars));
```

=> 11518 # fix it

```
SELECT nextval('scholars_id_seq');
```

=> 11519 # normal