# Compare the last_value of a sequence with the MAX(id) of a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence

In my dataBase i have 120 tables , and each table get his own sequence like this :

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('mySequence'::regclass),
...
```

Sometimes i am forced to add some data from postgres and it create a problem with the sequence : each time i add an information the sequence isn't updated

**my question is** : is there any sql request i can use to list the table with the sequence and compare the `last_value FROM my sequence` with the `MAX(id) FROM myTable`

**Additionnal question** : is there any risque to compare the `last_value` with `MAX(id)`

Comment: "is there any risque to compare the last_value with MAX(id)" - yes, if you have multiple connections writing.

Comment: @MitchWheat i am not firing multiple queries in the same time if this is what you mean by multiple connections writing the thing is sometimes i am forced to access (edit and delete) my data from postgres and it kind of diturbe my sequence

Comment: Why not simply reset the sequence after the inserts? See e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23390399/330315

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i want to detect the error between the current id and the sequence but i will use your solution in the futur

Comment: @YagamiLight: and what do you do if you detect the discrepancy? Most certainly sync the sequence, right?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes but i have to know witch table create the problem imagine i have to search 120 tables