# Fetching id field of an entity in the SQL Transaction

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, transactions

I have the following schema.

```
Person(pid, pname)
Beer(bid, bname)
Likes(pid,bid)
```

I would like to insert a likes item. However, I am accepting the following format for the new users : `(Pid, pname, bid, bname)`.

I would like to create a transaction for that to avoid conflict ( This is a highly simplified version of my real problem but the issue is the same). In my Person table, I set `pid` Auto-Increment(or Serial in Postgresql). Also the same goes for `bid`.

I have stuck in a point where I know the Person does not exist but the beer exists. So, I have to create a Person, then add an entity to Likes relation.

As far as I know, when I use the Autocommit(false) in dB, the transaction won't save until the commit. So, should I change the db design:

- Change the auto-increment field to a normal integer, not null field.
- In the transaction, after the autoCommit(false) has begun, read the last entry of the person
- Increment it by one while creating the new person
- Then create likes relation

Or, is there any other way around or do I miss something about transactions?

Here is what I have done so far:

```
try {
    String add_person_sql = "INSERT INTO Person (name) VALUES(?)";
    PreparedStatement add_person_statement = mydb.prepareStatement(add_person_sql);

    String add_likes_sql = "INSERT INTO Likes (pid, bid) VALUES(?, ?)";
    PreparedStatement add_likes_statement = mydb.prepareStatement(add_likes_sql);

    mydb.setAutoCommit(false);

    add_person_statement.setString(1, pname);
    // The problem is, without saving the person I cannot know the id of the person

    // AFAIK, this execution is not finished until commit occurs
    add_person_statement.executeQuery();
    // How can I fetch person's id
    add_likes_statement.setString(1, pid); 
    add_likes_statement.setString(2, bid);

    add_likes_statement.executeQuery();

    mydb.commit();
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
    mydb.rollback();
}
```

Comment: "*Increment it by one while creating the new person*" do **NOT** do that. It's slow and what's even worse, it won't work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell JDBC to return the generated ID from the insert statement, then you can use that ID to insert into the `likes` table:

```
mydb.prepareStatement(add_person_sql, new String[]{"pid"});
```

The second parameter tells the driver to return the generated value for the `pid` column.

Alternatively you can use

```
mydb.prepareStatement(add_person_sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

that tells the driver to detect the auto increment columns.

Then run the insert using `executeUpdate()`

```
add_person_statement.setString(1, pname);
add_person_statement.executeUpdate();

int newPid = -1;
ResultSet idResult = add_person.getGeneratedKeys();
if (idResult.next()) {
   newPid = idResult.getInt(1);
}

add_likes_statement.setString(1, newPid); 
add_likes_statement.setString(2, bid);

add_likes_statement.executeUpdate();

mydb.commit();
```

Comment: So, the jdbc can return the value, even if the transaction is not finished(not committed)

Comment: @qds52625: yes. it's essentially using an `INSERT INTO .... RETURNING ...` statement https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#id-1.9.3.152.5

Comment: Thanks, @a_horse_with_no_name.

I have one more thing to ask:

`CREATE TABLE Person(
    pid SERIAL,
    name TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (pid)
);` When I try to insert in this table, JDBC returns me an error:

detailMessage "ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "Person_pkey"\n  Detail: Key (pid)=(1) already exists." (id=66)

Comment: @qds52625: then you inserted into the table by providing the ID value yourself and the sequence is out of sync. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243

Comment: Ok, thanks to you I have figured out. In the population step of the database, I was setting ids. I let the job to postgresql and it works fine. Much appreciated