# How to use sub-queries correctly inside a Postgresql query

Tags: postgresql, database-sequence

I'm having troubles resetting the sequences as automatically as possible.
I'm trying to use the next query from phpPgAdmin:

```
SELECT SETVAL('course_subjects_seq', (SELECT MAX(subject_id) FROM course_subjects));
```

Somehow this query returns:

```
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

pointing to the first `SELECT SETVAL`

The next query will give the same error:

```
SELECT setval("course_subjects_seq", COALESCE((SELECT MAX(subject_id) FROM course_subjects), 1))
```

Can anyone point me to what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume the double quotes in your 2nd example are a typo? To make the question unambiguous, we'd need to see the actual table definition. Assuming `subject_id` is a `serial` or `bigserial` column? (And please *always* disclose your version of Postgres.)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by doing so:

setval function requires regclass, bigint and boolean as arguments, therefore I added the type casts:

```
SELECT setval('course_subjects_seq'::regclass, COALESCE((SELECT MAX(subject_id) FROM course_subjects)::bigint, 1));
```

`::regclass`

and `::bigint`

Comment: The cast to `regclass` isn't really necessary. The main difference is that you used single quotes `'` to pass a string constant, not double quotes `"` which indicate an identifier

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery at all here. Can be a single `SELECT`:

```
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('course_subjects', 'subject_id')
            , COALESCE(max(subject_id) + 1, 1)
            , false)  -- not called yet
FROM   course_subjects;
```

Assuming `subject_id` is a `serial` column, [`pg_get_serial_sequence()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) is useful so you don't have to know the sequence name (which is an implementation detail, really).

`SELECT` with an aggregate function like `max()` *always* returns a single row, even if the underlying table has no rows. The value is NULL in this case, that's why you have `COALESCE` in there.

But if you call `setval()` with 1, the next sequence returned number will be ***2***, not 1, since that is considered to be called already. There is an overloaded [variant of `setval()` with a 3rd, boolean parameter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html): *`is_called`*, which makes it possible to actually start from ***1*** in this case like demonstrated.

Related:

- [How to reset postgres' primary key sequence when it falls out of sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync/23390399#23390399)