# Write C# code for Sequence change on failure that works with PostGre

Tags: c#, sequence

If I specify a wrong ID , or the JSON is invalid my sequence in PostGre is kept. If i have 2 objects already in the database with ID 1 and ID 2, on failure of creation of third object and then success it will create it with ID 4.

I have looked into ways to resolve this. There is this topic:

[How to reset postgres' primary key sequence when it falls out of sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync)

However, I do not like to use that SQL code in PostGre , simply because a database is created on a use of specific function of a user.

Is there a way to disable it using C# code or send a command to postgre using C# ? I can use is inject the SQL query in C# and send it to PostGre, but I have read that this is a bad practice.

There is not much information regarding this on the web.

Under law our invoices must be sequential and their number is created by using the ID.

Comment: Why do you care whether your IDs are sequential without gaps?

Comment: In that case, I wouldn't base them on ID (directly). Can you post how you do it right now?