# How to increment serial id after having received id values manually?

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I am in the process of migrating data from mysql to postgres. To this end I have exported mysql tables to .json files which I then process using [node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com/) so that the data conforms to the new model defined in postgres. In this process when I make an insert to postgres of every table I include the id.

Here an example

```
const query = {
    text: `INSERT INTO public.table ( id, name ) VALUES ( $1, $2 )`,
    values: [id, name],
};

try {
    await connection.query(query);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
}
```

All good up to here. The scenario I have now is that in the context of the new application when creating a record the id value is not increased. I read about it and understand it is the case described in this [post](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20041130052832.GA87521%40winnie.fuhr.org)

The backend of the application is implemented in typeorm. My question is how in the context of typeorm I can execute the directives ALTER SEQUENCE or setval() suggested in the previous answer

I will appreciate some guidance if I am misinterpreting the solution of the problem

I attach an example of the definition of one of the entities and table

```
@Entity()
export class SomeName {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;
}
```

In database context `id` is declared as `serial`

Answer (score 1):

I got to solve this problem following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3698777/615274

Basically

First check

```
select max(id) from public.user; -- 35

select nextval('user_id_seq'); -- 5
```

The solution

```
SELECT setval('user_id_seq', max(id)) FROM user;
```

I need to do this on every table sequence

If I have missed something relevant, I appreciate comments

Comment: You can do it once for all tables using a sequence: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62060505/330315