# Setting the Postgres 9.6 Current Sequence Values of All Tables to Max ID values of all Parent Tables

Tags: postgresql

Postgres allows for auto-increment of the Primary Key value `SERIAL` is used at DDL. With this, a `sequence` property for the table is also created along with the table. However, when tuples are inserted manually, the `sequence` `current value` does not get updated.

For One table at a time we can use SQL like this
`SELECT setval('<table>_id_seq', COALESCE((SELECT MAX(id) FROM your_table), 1), false);` wherein we need to manually set the `<table>_id_seq' and` id' attribute name.

The problem becomes labourious if there are multiple tables. So is there any generalised method to set `current value` for all `sequences` to the `MAX(<whatever_sequence_attribute_is>)`?

Answer (score 0):

Yup! Got it

First run the following SQL

`SELECT  'SELECT setval(' || quote_literal(quote_ident(sequence_namespace.nspname) || '.' || quote_ident(class_sequence.relname)) || ', COALESCE((SELECT MAX(' ||quote_ident(pg_attribute.attname)|| ') FROM '  || quote_ident(table_namespace.nspname)|| '.'||quote_ident(class_table.relname)|| '), 1), false)' || ';' FROM pg_depend  INNER JOIN pg_class AS class_sequence ON class_sequence.oid = pg_depend.objid  AND class_sequence.relkind = 'S' INNER JOIN pg_class AS class_table ON class_table.oid = pg_depend.refobjid INNER JOIN pg_attribute  ON pg_attribute.attrelid = class_table.oid AND pg_depend.refobjsubid = pg_attribute.attnum INNER JOIN pg_namespace as table_namespace ON table_namespace.oid = class_table.relnamespace INNER JOIN pg_namespace AS sequence_namespace ON sequence_namespace.oid = class_sequence.relnamespace ORDER BY sequence_namespace.nspname, class_sequence.relname;`

The result window will show as many SQL statements as `sequences` are there in the DB. Copy all the SQL statements and Execute all. The `current value` of all `sequences` will get updated.

**Note:** Please Note that the major SQL will only generate SQLs and **WILL NOT UPDATE** the `sequences`. One has to copy all the SQL Statements from the Result and execute.

Comment: The better solution is available at this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62059947/how-to-bulk-update-sequence-id-postgresql-for-all-tables