# Postgresql: why no automatic updates of a id sequence after bulk insert

Tags: postgresql, sequence, primary-key, bulkinsert

Assuming, I have this table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.test
(
    "Id" smallint NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    "Value" character varying(10)
);
```

and I insert some rows:

```sql
INSERT INTO public.test ("Id", "Value") VALUES 
(1, 'Val1'),
(2, 'Val2'),
(3, 'Val3');
```

Everything is fine. But now I want to insert another row

```sql
INSERT INTO public.test ("Value") VALUES ('Val9');
```

and I get the error: `duplicate key violates unique constraint`

That is, how I learned, because the pk-sequence is out of sync. But why? Is there any senseful reason why pg do not update the sequence automatically? After single INSERTs it works well, but after BULK not? Is there any way to avoid these manually updates? Or is it standard to [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync) every pk-sequence of every table after every little bulk insert (if there is a serial id)?

For futher information, I use `GENERATED BY DEFAULT` because I want to migrate a database from mysql and I want to preserve the IDs. And I would like the idea of having a lot of flexibility with the keys (similar to mysql).

But what do I not understand here?

Is it possible to correct the sequence automatically without knowing it's concrete name?

Sorry, more questions than I wanted to ask. But ... I don't understand this concept. Would appreciate some explanation.

Comment: "*After single INSERTs it works well*" - I doubt that. Yes, if you overwrite the default and ignore the sequence, you always have to correct it afterwards.

Comment: You are right, I tried it just in the moment again, and there is the same error like on bulk insert. Ok, at least consistent behavior. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe my problem is coming from mysql. There I have a (really working) default sequence (without any manually doing), and full fexibility too. I can change a id and next time will nevertheless be inserted a correct new id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `BY DEFAULT` in `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY`. That means that you can override the automatically generated keys, like your `INSERT` statements do.

When that happens, the sequence that implements the identity column is not modified. So when you insert a row *without* specifying `"Id"`, it will start counting at 1, which causes the conflict.

Never override the default. To make sure this doesn't happen by accident, use `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`.

Comment: …and for doing it on purpose (such as a bulk import followed by correction of the sequence counter), you can still use `OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE`.