# How To Alter primary Key default Value?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
ALTER TABLE hr_leave ALTER COLUMN id DEFAULT (select Max(id)+2)
```

How can I write this query with a prober way to alter primary key default value equal max id +2

Comment: Use a sequence instead.

Comment: How ?
if you can write a query because I'm bad at sql

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync

Comment: @AhmedElsayed glad to hear. Consider accepting my answer, so that other users know the issue has been solved: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

First create a `SEQUENCE`:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE myseq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 2;
```

In case table `hr_leave` already contains records and you wish to change the initial value of your new sequence to the max `id` value of `hr_leave` do the following:

```
SELECT setval('myseq', (SELECT max(id) FROM hr_leave));
```

.. then finally change the column `id` to use the sequence `myseq`:

```
ALTER TABLE hr_leave ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('myseq');
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8859b408eb7615d8a3cb31aeacc9931f)