# ALTER TABLE in Postgres with a subquery

Tags: postgresql, identity-column, database-sequence

I am trying to update the identity sequence in my table, but I am getting a syntax error.

This works:

```
ALTER TABLE "ApiResourceScopes" ALTER COLUMN "Id"
   RESTART SET START 145
```

This doesn't work:

```
ALTER TABLE "ApiResourceScopes" ALTER COLUMN "Id"
   RESTART SET START (
      select coalesce(max("Id"), '0') + 1 as "Id"
      FROM public."ApiResourceScopes"
   )
```

How could I set a value with a subquery in an `ALTER TABLE` statement?

Note: my table foes not have `nextval('somesequence')` in the column default, but an identity column, so directly updating the sequence is not an option.

Comment: *doest not works* means? any error message?

Comment: yes , error message from postgres:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 3: ...sourceScopes" ALTER COLUMN "Id" RESTART SET START (select co...
                                                             ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 71

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync

Comment: "*my table has not a sequence function, jus a identity Id, so.. update the sequences not its a option*" - an identity column **does** use a sequence in the background. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23390399

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a subquery in that place. The simplest solution would be to first run the query and then an appropriate `ALTER TABLE`. If you insist on doing it in a single statement, use something like

```
SELECT setval(
          pg_get_serial_sequence(
             '"ApiResourceScopes"',
             'Id'
          ),
          (select coalesce(max("Id"), '0')
           FROM public."ApiResourceScopes")
       );
```

Comment: hi, Laureaz, thanks a lot for your answer but iam getting this error ERROR:  relation "apiresourcescopes" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01 , remember that my table does not have a sequence function,

Comment: Then double quote the names.

Comment: thank you a lot Laurenz Albel, it worked with a simple quote in 'Id'!!! you were a really helpful