# Django starts primary key from 1 when there is already data in database

Tags: django, database, postgresql, pg-restore

I have a pg database created by **migrate** with Django, all the tables have been created successfully and are empty at the start.

Now I have to fill one of the tables from a database backup created by **pgdump**. This database has a table **transactions** which contains data (consider no FK, and the schema of the table is same), so using pgrestore, I restored only that transaction table from the database backup. Everything restored and data is shown in the Django web app as well.

**But** Now when I create a new entry in that table using django web app, the django starts assigning the primary key from 1 to the newly created entry, but as the table is restored from a database backup, that id already exists, if I try again, django will try to assign PK 2, then 3 and so on. But those transactions have already been restored from DB backup

How to tell Django the last transaction id so that it can start assigning from there?

Comment: Django does not dispatch primary keys, you will need to look to the sequence in your postgreSQL database and set the start of the index of that primary key to a different value.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea how to do that, but considering your suggestion and a little googling, I resolved the problem.

I restarted the sequence from the last id +1 using 
`ALTER SEQUENCE public.transaction_id_seq RESTART 156098`
, and it works fine now.
Thanks again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django does not decide how the primary keys are generated for an [**`AutoField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#autofield) (or [**`BigAutoField`** <sup>[Djang-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#bigautofield) or [**`SmallAutoField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#smallautofield)): it is the database that assigns values for these.

For PostgreSQL, the database makes use of sequences, and each time it has to determine a value it updates the sequence, such that next time a different value will be given. You thus need to update that sequence.

As you found out yourself, you can do this with:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE public.modelname_id_seq RESTART some_value
```