# Recreating sequence starting from last value +1 in PostgreSql

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, sequence

In my Java project, I have a sequence called `room_id_seq` and after updating some inheritance in Spring Data JPA, now I need to drop and recreate this sequence starting from the last value + 1 from the dropped one. For example, if the last value of `room_id_seq` is 100, then after dropping it my newly created `room_id_seq` will start from 101.

So, how can I write sql to achieve this? Should I use a new name for new sequence and after creating it using the last value of previous, should I drop previous one?

Comment: Are you maybe looking for a solution [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync)?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems better for my situation. Voted up.

Answer (score 0):

No need to drop the sequence, just adjust the value using `setval()`

```
select setval('room_id_seq', 101);
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't now the next value. Because it will be changed based on the time when code is passed on pipeline. In this scene, I need to get the current value by querying from db.

Comment: @Jonathan: Then replace `101` with the query that returns you the "current value" or pass it as a parameter.