# Id sequence is not incrementing after inserting a row with id

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

I have table `user` (`id, firstname, lastname`) and `id` is defined as

```
id int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('user_id_seq'::regclass)
```

But when I first insert a row through database using this SQL:

```
INSERT INTO user (id, firstname, lastname) 
VALUES((SELECT(MAX(id) + 1) FROM user), firstname, lastname);
```

the data gets inserted, but when I am hitting through API then `id` is not returned, I get an error

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint 'user_pkey'

This is because in the previous insertion through database sequence is not updated.

How to resolve this?

Comment: The sqecuence is only used if you do not explicitly give the id

Comment: Please share more details. Is this a MySQL problem, or a PostgreSQL problem? And how is this related to [tag:create-table]?

Comment: You're not supposed to insert an id value when the column already has a nextval default value. Simply do `INSERT INTO user (firstname,lastname) VALUES ('firstname', 'lastname')`.

Comment: A `default` value is used when **no** value is specified during an INSERT. You are providing a value for the `id` column, so the `default` isn't used. Additionally: the `max(id)+1` approach will fail if you have concurrent transactions. And finally: `identity` columns are the recommended approach to auto-generate primary key values

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is there any way I could get the sequence updated even if someone gives id? or by changing Id Default value?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync

Comment: yeah i reset the sequence at once but how can I maintain sequence updated even if someone insert along id in future?

Answer (score 2):

The only good way to prevent that is to use an identity column instead:

```
ALTER TABLE tab
   ALTER id
   ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START 1000000);
```

That automatically creates a sequence, and a normal insert statement is not allowed to override the default.

Comment: how to start identity with max(id)+1. Because it start with Id=1 and gives ```violates unique constraint 'user_pkey'```

Comment: I don't understand. If it is a new column, why do you have to start with a higher value?

Comment: It isn't a new column. It is a existing table where id sequence is not getting updated

Comment: I see. I changed the answer to modify an existing column, including a higher start value.