# Should I reset the sequence to MAX(id) or MAX(id)+1 after a data import?

Tags: postgresql

As stated in the title, should I reset a PG sequence to MAX(id) or to MAX(id)+1 after a data import?

```
-- is what SELECT MAX(id) FROM my_table or
-- SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM my_table 

ALTER SEQUENCE my_table_id_seq RESTART WITH what;
```

If I pick a table and do `SELECT MAX(id) FROM my_table`, I get x, then I look into the sequence last_value and it shows `x=MAX(id)` and NOT `MAX(id)+1`

So to me it locally means that PG keeps track (and should be reset to) the last value i.e. `MAX(id)` and not to `MAX(id)+1`

Comment: would the id not increment automatically with every insert?

Comment: it has the concept of current and next value so not sure and thus the OP

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync has the relevant discussion

Comment: @Bergi, thanks but there is a discussion and not a spot answer to my question. The different answers dont bother too much about the detail between MAX or MAX+1. I believe should be MAX and not MAX+1, using MAX+1 would leave holes.

Comment: @SkyWalker The "discussion" hinges on calling `set_val` with `true` or `false`. But most importantly, heed [Craig Ringer's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync#comment79586215_244265): "*If your application cares about gaps in sequences, your application is broken. Gaps in sequences are normal, and can occur due to unplanned database shutdowns, transaction rollbacks after errors, etc.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersequence.html say

> The […] clause `RESTART WITH restart` changes the current value of the sequence. This is similar to calling the [`setval` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html) with `is_called = false`: the specified value will be returned by the *next* call of `nextval`.

So you'll need `COALESCE((SELECT MAX(id) FROM my_table), 0) + 1`, or the next `nextval()` call will return a value that already exists in your table.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I confirmed this by preping a MRE test. The subtlety is in the `is_called` setting.