# Issues with Sequence Synchronization and Duplicate Key Violation after migration to v3.2.0.Final

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

Recently, I migrated a service from Quarkus 2.7 to the latest version, 3.2.0.Final. The migration process went smoothly, and the project builds successfully. However, I encountered a problem when attempting to write data to a PostgreSQL database.
nitially, I faced the error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "public.revinfo_seq" does not exist
  Position: 16
                at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675)
                at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2365)
                at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:355)
                at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:490)
                at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:408)
                at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:166)
                at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:118)
                at io.agroal.pool.wrapper.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:78)
                at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:
```

To resolve this, I renamed the current sequence from `info_rev_seq` to `revinfo_seq`  since Hibernate 6 introduced a change in sequence naming strategy https://jpa-buddy.com/blog/hibernate6-whats-new-and-why-its-important/

After fixing the sequence name, the above problem was resolved. However, I discovered another issue that emerged after some time.

I encountered the following error:

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement [ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_revinfo"
Detail: Key (rev)=(60) already exists.] [insert into public.REVINFO (REVTSTMP,REV) values (?,?)]
  at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:95)
  at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:56)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:108)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:278)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.AbstractMutationExecutor.performNonBatchedMutation(AbstractMutationExecutor.java:108)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.MutationExecutorSingleNonBatched.performNonBatchedOperations(MutationExecutorSingleNonBatched.java:40)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.AbstractMutationExecutor.execute(AbstractMutationExecutor.java:53)
  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.InsertCoordinator.doStaticInserts(InsertCoordinator.java:170)
  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.InsertCoordinator.coordinateInsert(InsertCoordinator.java:112)
  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2761)
  at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:102)
  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:606)
  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:358)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
  at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127)
  ...
  Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_revinfo"
  Detail: Key (rev)=(60) already exists.
```

The structure of the `revinfo` table is as follows:

```
create table revinfo
(
    rev      bigserial,
    revtstmp bigint
);

alter table revinfo
    add constraint pk_revinfo
        primary key (rev);
```

Upon investigation, it became apparent that the sequence was becoming out of sync. For example, the `revinfo` table contained **54 rows**, but the `sequence` had a value of **23**. I manually fixed the sequence to align with the correct value, but it eventually became out of sync again.

The issue seems to be related to sequence synchronization. Although the specific cause is yet to be determined, factors such as transaction rollbacks, concurrent operations, or improper sequence management might be contributing to the problem.

I suspect that the migration to `Quarkus 3.2.0.Final` might have influenced the behavior, as the sequence synchronization was working correctly before the migration.

I am also using Hibernate Envers for auditing my tables, including the `revinfo` table. However, since the issue arises even without any reference to the `revinfo` table in my primary tables, it seems that the problem lies in the sequence synchronization rather than the auditing itself.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem and could provide advice on solving the issue and identifying its root cause?
Your insights and suggestions would be greatly appreciated in resolving the sequence synchronization problem mentioned above.

Please feel free to share any experiences or recommendations that could help in troubleshooting and resolving the issue effectively.
Thank you in advance for your assistance

P.S. The database being used is PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

You have to resync your sequence and lock it to last sequence value, to do that I have used the following query:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM your_table;
-- This should be higher than the last result.

SELECT nextval('your_table_id_seq');
-- If it's not higher... run this set the sequence last to your highest id. 

BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE your_table IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
-- Update the sequence
SELECT setval('your_table_id_seq', COALESCE((SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM your_table), 1), false);
COMMIT;
```

For reference you can have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/244265/8411718

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend checking out this migration guide https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/wiki/Migration-Guide-3.0:-Hibernate-ORM-5-to-6-migration

The issue you are encountering most likely comes from [this particular change](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/wiki/Migration-Guide-3.0:-Hibernate-ORM-5-to-6-migration#sequence-increment-size), where the default increment size changed from 1 to 50.

You could try explicitly setting the increment size back to 1 and see if that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot set the increment size to 1 because all my entities extend the `BaseEntity` that has 
`public class BaseDbEntity extends PanacheEntityBase {`
 `@Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;`

Answer (score 0):

You should set the increment size of your sequence to 50.

See https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/wiki/Migration-Guide-3.0:-Hibernate-ORM-5-to-6-migration#sequence-increment-size :

> Use DDL (SQL such as `alter sequence […​]`) to set the increment size of your sequences to the right value, i.e. to the allocation size of your identifier generators, which defaults to 50 since Hibernate ORM 6.